# FlasCC open-source download?

Tags: alchemy, flascc

FlasCC uses several customized GPL libraries, such as SWIG.  Aren't they supposed to provide the source for these libraries?  Where can I download it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's buried in their "[FlasCC Third Party Notices](http://www.adobe.com/products/eula/third_party/pdfs/Flascc_ThirdPartyPage_2012-09-11.pdf)" PDF:

- http://www.adobe.com/go/flascc_oss